# Error when trying to get sum of column from database in Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony

I'm trying to get a sum of several values in a database column:

```
                $goalsScored = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('sum(homeGoals)')
                ->from('LoginLoginBundle:Matchgame', 'mg')
                ->where("mg.homeTeam LIKE '" . $oneTeam->getTeamid()."'")
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

I get following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 11 near 'homeGoals) FROM': Error: 'homeGoals' is not defined.
```

homeGoals IS defined in my database, so why do I get this error? Is it because some of the values are null?

Comment: You should get into the habit of using parameters: `->where('mg.homeTeam = :team')->setParameter('team', $oneTeam)` - Doctrine handles the identifier resolution automatically assuming you've set up Entity Associations correctly. @devilcius has correctly answered your problem however

Comment: That is idd cleaner code, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table alias is missing in your select:

```
    $goalsScored = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('sum(mg.homeGoals)')
    ->from('LoginLoginBundle:Matchgame', 'mg')
    ->where("mg.homeTeam LIKE '" . $oneTeam->getTeamid()."'")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```